# InlineKeyboardMarkup in telegram bot sdk laravel

Tags: laravel, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm using telegram-bot-sdk for developing telegram bot in my Laravel project but now i have problem and i cant add InlineKeyboardMarkup or InlineKeyboardbutton to my posts because this package doesn't have this method and just handle Reply Keyboard Markup and Reply Keyboard Hide how can i add these to my project or package?
[telegram-bot-sdk](https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/v2.0/docs/keyboards)

Comment: what do you  mean by " this package doesn't have this method" ?

Comment: i want to add InlineKeyboardbutton  to my posts- how can do it in laravel?

Comment: create the keyboard array and pass it to result obkect